# onDoupleTap does not fire

Tags: android, android-mapview, gesture, double-click

I wanna make a mapview that responds to double click and get the geopoint of the clicked place and return it to the caller activity .. I test my app in eclipse emulator, but when I double click the map nothing happens and my onDoubleTap() method never enters

here is my code

```
public class MYMapActivity extends MapActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener{

GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mymapview);
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), this);
        gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
    }
@Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent mev) {
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        Projection p = mapView.getProjection();
        GeoPoint geoPoint = p.fromPixels((int) mev.getX(), (int) mev.getY());
        int latitude = geoPoint.getLatitudeE6();
        int longitude = geoPoint.getLongitudeE6();
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        resultIntent.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
        resultIntent.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
            float distanceY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

whats wrong or whats missed that makes my double tap never fires ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out whats missing on my code and I write it here for any one who can meet the same problem

first:

I must add this line after the initializing of gestureDetector object

```
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, this);
        gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
        mapView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
```

second:
I must return true in onDown method since it is called with every click and double tap depends on it

```
@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    return true;
}
```

thats all what you need to implement doubleTap listener in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Let your activity implement only `OnGestureListener` and inside `onCreate()`, do

```
    gd.setOnDoubleTapListener(new OnDoubleTapListener()  
            {  //all the override functions of the listener go here // 
});
```

After `onCreate()` comes all those functions you want to override for `onGesturelistener`, including this one you have forgotten:

```
@Override  
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  
    {  
        return gd.onTouchEvent(event);//return the double tap events  
    }
```

Comment: sorry, but didn't work also :( ... what is the difference between your code and mine